# Issue with banning system on login

Tags: php, mysql

I've created the following banning system when a user logins on my site. It checks if the user is banned, and then follows a process to gather information, and finally brings up a notice and doesn't let the user login. However, this does not happen and I can login fine. Any help would be appriciated.

```
    $un9 = "gdscei";
    $checkban = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bans WHERE usr = '" .$un9. "'") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($checkban) != 0){
            $query7 = "SELECT * FROM bans WHERE usr = '".$un9."'";
    $result7 = mysql_query($query7) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row7 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result7)) {
        $reas = $row7['reas'];
        $timeb = $row7['time'];
        $tban = $row7['tban'];
            $tip = $row7['ipd'];
    };
    if($timeb == "perm"){
        $bant = "Permanent";
    }else{
        $bant = $timeb;
    };
    $checkusrdel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$un9."'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($checkusrdel) != 0){
    $acdel = "n";
    }else{
    $acdel = "y";
    };
    if(empty($tip) && acdel == "n"){
    $bank = "account ban";
    }else if($acdel == "y" && empty($tip)){
    $bank = "account deleted";
    }else if($acdel == "y" && $tip){
    $bank = "account deleted + IP ban";
    }else{
    $bank = "account ban + IP ban";
    };
    $notice = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("You have been banned, as followed: "'.$bank.'". Your ban lasts until "'.$bant.'"."); window.open("login.php","_self");</script>';
    };
```

Comment: What result are you getting and what result do you expect? This would be helpful to know, as we cannot see what your database tables contain.

Comment: I don't get a result, that's the issue. the page works fine as a whole, but for whatever reason it doesn't bring up the notice it should, and just lets me log in.

Comment: So we can assume there definitely **is** a record with `bans.usr = 'gdscei'` in the table and bans.usr is unique?

Comment: Please post which values `$reas`, `$timeb`, `$tban` and `$tip` have immediately after the `while` loop.

Comment: `$reas` = `Blablabla` , `$timeb` = `20 April 2011`, and `$tip` is empty in the case of my user account.

Comment: Meanwhile I'm sure the `$notice = ..` is the reason why the alert doesn't show up, but just for the record, what does `$tban` contain?

Comment: ...not related, but wow you have some funky variable names

Comment: True, I do have some funky ones. This is not even close to the strange names i've given to my variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simpler than you may have imagined:

```
$notice = '<script type="text/javascript">alert("You have been banned, as followed: '.$bank.'. Your ban lasts until '.$bant.'."); window.open("login.php","_self");</script>';
```

In short, you shouldn't have used brackets twice in the JavaScript alert message.

**Addition:** Do not forget to echo the notice in the end. The excerpt of your PHP script doesn't show me anything like that. If you want to show your homepage after the ban check, just use the `die`-function to output a message and terminate the current script if the user is banned. In your case, just add the following after having defined the variable `$notice`:

```
die($notice);
```

Comment: I changed it, but still, it does not display the notice.

Comment: By the way, which web browsers and operating systems were you using to test your script?

Comment: the `die($notice);` makes it work. I actually did try to echo the `$notice`, but that was in the actual HTML code, and as so probably forced the other code to run and make it so it did login. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

You are providing too much information to the user, all they need to know is that they are banned, not the type of ban.

```
if (banned)
{
  ajax.display("Ban HAMMER!!");
}
else
{
  user.logon();
  redirect("location: home.php");
}
```